# How do I set up the database in a Node app?

Tags: django, node.js, npm

I'm a Django developer getting to grips with Node/Express. I have been given an existing Node repo to work with. How do I set up the database?

In other words, what's the Node equivalent of editing `localsettings.py` with the database name and login details, and then running:

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
```

to set up the database schema for the app?

I know the app has a Mongo back-end, but that's all I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't something as sophisticated as that. You will need to connect to it, every time you want to use it. Make sure you've set mongodb up, and if you have not, this is an excellent [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fcbGY4ZUxcA) on how to set it up.

Now that you've got it as a service, you can start using mongodb. First, install `mongoose`, like so:

```
npm install mongoose
```

Then you can connect to your mongodb server like so:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/<db_name_here>");

// Sample schema
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    name: String,
    age: Number
});
```

You can learn more about how to use mongoose [here ->](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html).